# Events not working in ES6 Class

Tags: javascript

I have a sample ES6 class which I convert using Babel. The issue is the events are not getting initiated with my code.

```
import $ from 'jquery';

export default class Test{
    constructor(){
        this.close_popup = $(".welcome-message-close");
        this.events();
    }

    events(){
        this.close_popup.on("click", this.hidePopup.bind(this));
    }

    hidePopup(){
        // code to close popup.
    }

}
```

When I click on the close button (having class "welcome-message-close" ), the hidePopup() function is not getting called. How can I make the events working?

Comment: Are you sure you initialized the class (`new Test()`) somewhere? Tested it in JSFiddle and seems to work as-is: https://jsfiddle.net/zkq1uh5e/

Comment: Are you creating your class after the elements exist in the page?